# Calculate the duration of a Flash animation from an SWF?

Tags: flash

I have a big pile of .SWF files. I need to get the duration of the animations for each one programmatically, preferably in .NET.

ByteScout told me that they're all single-frame animations, and the only way to find out how long they run is to watch them play.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

"Single-frame" means that the animations are happening in some child object, which has been put on the main timeline's stage.  You will have to dig deeper to find the `totalFrames` of the children (or other descendants).  If the classes are public, you can do this by setting up a Flash file to load and display the frame length of all objects on the stage.  .NET == ??.

Comment: What can I load the Flash file with (from code) to get to the objects on the stage? Are there Flash-editing libraries for .NET? (Or anything else?)

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked in Flash with .NET.  If I were working on this, I would build another SWF program using Actionscript or Flex that would load and scour the SWFs.  If you would like more help, please contact me at my junk email: testdee@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I use the [FlashHeaderReader](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_27421592.html) class for my own. Unfortunately, it doesn't supported compressed files (starts with CWS - [Adobe spetification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf))

I've changed the class a bit. And it can work with compressed swf's too. This class requires ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll. You can download it from [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jayakrishnagudla/blogcode/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.zip) or [ICSharpCode](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx).

I've changed a constructor only

```
    public FlashHeaderReader(String filename)
    {
        Height = 0;
        Width = 0;
        FrameCount = 0;
        FrameRate = 0;
        _currentIndex = 0;
        Error = false;
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
        _data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(_data, 0, _data.Length);
        fs.Close();

        if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_data, 0, 3).Equals("CWS"))
        {
            _mIsCompressed = true;
        }

        if (_mIsCompressed)
        {
            var list = new List<byte>(_data);
            var header = list.GetRange(1, 7).ToArray();
            list.RemoveRange(0, 8);
            _data = list.ToArray();
            using (var str = new MemoryStream(_data))
            using (var dStr = new InflaterInputStream(str))
            {

                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                list = new List<byte> {(byte) 'F'};
                list.AddRange(header);
                int count;
                while ((count = dStr.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0)
                {
                    list.AddRange(buffer.Take(count));
                }
                _data = list.ToArray();
            }
        }




        ParseHeader();
    }
```

Hope it'll help you.